# Why does App Store start updating Xcode when latest version already installed?

Tags: mac, mojave, xcode, mac-appstore, software-update

I have installed Xcode 11.0 manually from an `Xcode_11.xip` file. My Xcode installed successfully and it shows version 11.0 in its about page. But whenever I boot my Mac, the App Store always starts updating the same version 11.0, which is around ~7GB. It never succeeds before I turn my Mac off due to my low bandwidth.

On the next boot, it again starts updating from the beginning. That's an annoying situation for me and I need to stop updating from App Store app. Or if it's possible, I need to let App Store point to the manually installed version and stop bothering me.

How can I get rid of this issue?

```
System Software Overview:

  System Version:   macOS 10.14.6 (18G103) Mojave
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 18.7.0
  Boot Volume:  Home
  Boot Mode:    Normal

Xcode: Version 11.0 (11A420a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tweak that you can try:

1. Go to Finder -> Applications
2. Move Xcode.app to trash. (Here it will ask you if you want to cancel update).
3. Agree to cancel the update.
4. Go to Trash -> Xcode.app, right-click and click on "Put Back"
5. Re-start using Xcode and continue with your work.

Also, while you wait for XCode to update and you are in a slow internet connection, go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and download the latest version of XCode dmg using your Apple ID. The latest is 11.1 and they have 11.2 beta also.